# What does the word "managed" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A sentence in *THE ECONOMIST* "Only about 0.1% of true stories were shared by more than 1,000 people, but 1% of false stories **managed** between 1,000 and 100,000 shares." Is “managed” the synonym of "shared"?  But I cannot find this meaning in dictionary... Thanks.

Comment: I would suppose the article in *The Economist* to be about made-up stories whose authors had a specific purpose in mind when sharing the falsehoods, hence the stories themselves have a purpose. As Max says in his answer, the stories were able to achieve their goals to the extent mentioned, despite being a pack of lies.

Comment: share here is the term  used in social media: Share on Facebook, etc. So, when you share a story with someone, that is "a share".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, it means something like "were able to achieve". Here's a relevant entry from Dictionary.com:

> [manage](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/manage)
>   1. to bring about or succeed in accomplishing, sometimes despite difficulty or hardship:
>   *She managed to see the governor. How does she manage it on such a small income?*

I would say the "difficulty" here is that these stories were false, yet they were able to achieve many shares.